# What happen if a universal quantifier with a conjunction?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Theorically, they clearly explained that the universal is the quantifer combining with a multiple conjuction.So if in statements with that quantifier, they have to with a implication not a conjuction, but somehow I still see those can have, specifically is:

All dog owners are animal lovers, is:

∀x (∀y (Dog(y) ∧ Rear(x,y)) → AnimalLover(x)

but, Dogs are all animals, is:

∀y Dog(y) → Animal(y)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your formula reads "For everyone, if everything in the world is a dog and they own everything, then they are an animal lover". What you want instead is "Everyone who owns *some* dog is a animal lover, which translates with am existential quantifier for $y$.

In general, it is not forbidden to use $\forall$ with $\land$ or $\exists$ with $\to$ in the sense that it wouldn't be a syntactically well-formed formula, it just doesn't correspond to a situation we'd typically want to express.

Comment: Can i write it again like this ∀x (∀y (Dog(y)→ Rear(x,y)) → AnimalLover(x) ?

Comment: I had a mistake in my earlier version of my answer, sorry. See the updated version. The formula you're giving now translates as what I had said previously, "Everyone who owns every dog is an animal lover".

Comment: but i still thought is : For everyone, if everything in the world is a dog and they owned by everyone, then they are an animal lover?And if you say that not forbidden then in realistic that would be like this: ((Dog(A) ∧ Rear(x1,A)) ∧ (Dog(B) ∧ Rear(x1,B)) ∧... ∧ (Dog(N) ∧ Rear(x1,N)?

Comment: Correct. And that's a perfectly grammatical, but unusual thing to say.

Comment: oh,that's weird although this is in the lecture my teacher say it was correct and in syntactically it correct too

Comment: It is syntactically correct, i.e. a well-formed formula. But it is not a semantically correct translation of "Everyone who owns a dog is an animal lover". The correct translation for that is with the existential quantifier.

Comment: Yes, that why i explain that it have to be a existential quantifier to my teacher but was say it's not, and i was also say if it was exstential quantifier then it was be true cause at least a dog is rear by everyone not every dog  ,And partly this sentences was too ambiguity talk about how many dog

Comment: Possibly there's a language barrier here and the sentence your teacher gave you means something different than the English sentence we're discussing here. In any event, the truth conditions of formula with $\forall y$ and $\land$ does not correspond to what we mean by "Every dog owner is an animal lover".

Comment: I have to disagree, lemontree. The formula is basically saying that for anything that’s a dog and  for anyone who raises a dog, the ones who raise dogs are animal lovers. 

The first sentence could be open to interpretation since it is not a wff, as it has an odd number of brackets.

Comment: @Pdubya_24 Ah, I see your point. The problem is that the formula in the OP is missing brackets (at least one at the end, and another pair for clarity). I was assuming that the scope of the second universal quantifier is limited to the conjunction, as that's the part enclosed by the parentheses immediately following the variable. But if the formula as it's written is taken to mean that the second universal quantifier should scope over the implication with another pair of parentheses extending all the way to the right, then it makes a lot more sense. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if a universal quantifier with a conjunction?

If we assume that $\exists a: \neg P(a)$ for any predicate $P$, then $\forall a:[P(a) \land Q(a)]$ is a **contradiction** regardless of the truth value of $Q(a)$. Though technically valid, it is **not** something to be recommended in applications!

Proof: Using a form of natural deduction, we can formally prove $\exists a: \neg P(a) \implies \neg \forall a:[P(a) \land Q(a)]$ as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer - after @Pdubya_24 pointed out a possible misunderstanding:

The formula as you wrote it is missing brackets. The first opening bracket one is never closed (there should be another "$)$" at the end), and there should be another pair of brackets for what I believe is the intended interpretation. The way it is written, the structure of the formula is basically (inserting here a redundant pair of brackets for clarity)

$$\forall x ((\forall y (Dog(x) \land Raise(x,y))) \to AnimalLover(x))$$

i.e. the $\forall y $ ranges only over $(Dog(x) \land Raise(x,y))$. This is a well-formed sentence, but not a very useful one, as explained in my other answer.

What I believe the formula is meant to be is

$$\forall x (\forall y ((Dog(x) \land Raise(x,y)) \to AnimalLover(x)))$$

whith the $\forall y$ scoping all over $((Dog(x) \land Raise(x,y))) \to AnimalLover(x))$. In this case, the main operator of $\forall y$ is the implication, and the conjunction occurs only as a subformula on the left-hand side of the implication, not directly under $\forall$. So this is an instance of the common pattern $\forall y (\phi \to \psi)$, and not of the form $\forall y (\phi \land \psi)$, and nothing unusual is going on.

Comment: So after what u said i think:  Firstly, may be my book has wrong when write the quantifier ∀y instead ∃y, cause i see every lecture in English they always said: ∀X (∃ Y dog(Y ) & owns(X, Y )) ⇒ animalLover(X), Secondly,my book missed the bracket as you said before, Since, whatever that my book wrong or my teacher still assert that sentences was true, i still cant know for that.And Hopefully, its will fall into the cases you said its